# How to play Youtube videos using Video.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video.js

Is there a way to play Youtube videos using video.js? I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/94c07756dc1c3d301f25dd2ca54317335f6d4feb/docs/tech.md)
but can't seem to make it work. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can try https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube . Before using, I recommend you to read trough the bug reports. In particular, do not follow the advice to use the provided video.js version with the script. It seems to contain a vulnerability. The new version of video.js works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I used the latest version of video.js then included the vjs.youtube.js script from [https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) with this code: `<video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="320" height="264" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ" }'></video>` and it worked!

Comment: My problem now is, can I control it while playing? For example, pause the video if it's in 30 seconds of playing? Can't find it in docs. When I'm trying to incorporate video.js events, I already get an error.

Comment: @MoMo It ain't ready yet. Wait or use iframes. Heff is working on it. Check out the readme : "A JavaScript API for controlling the video that works consistently across video platforms (HTML5, Flash, and soon other players like youtube)".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! Luckily, while playing around with codes, and with the help of my colleague, we we're able to control the youtube video using video.js events.

Comment: @Ben, are you sure Heff is working on this? After reading https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/414, I think he isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested, it worked like a charm. Could hardly believe it. Just need to include the script vjs.youtube.js.  You can style the player as you please.

====================

Gee, this got downvoted as "not useful". What can I add? See here:

http://www.casedasole.it/video/YT.html

Look at the source. Video-js + vjs.youtube.js. It works.

Comment: Worked for me too, but only for videojs 4.6.  I was using 4.10, but that didn't work with vjs.video.js, so had to switch down.  I looked for this on github so I could update it, but but couldn't find it.  Thanks again!